# Cannot find system.spatial.data

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-5, asp.net-4.5

I just upgraded to .net 4.5rc [from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/hh854779.aspx) here and Entity Framework 5rc [from](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) here because I would like to work with the [System.Data.Spatial-classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But I cannot find the namespace in my solution. I tried searching for the classes in the object browser but without any luck.

Any ideas where I can find the classes / how to reference them ?

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

I think you also need VS 2012 RC because VS 2010 is not able to target .NET 4.5 specific features.